# Android detect if any view is using LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE

Tags: android

Is there any way to programatically detect if LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE is set for any windows currently opened?

My app will be running in the background.

I've attempted to use the following code, but it appears to always return true.

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    boolean ret =  (wm.getDefaultDisplay().getFlags() & Display.FLAG_SECURE) == Display.FLAG_SECURE;
    //ret is always true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using [getFlags()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getFlags()) method of Display and check if flag returned is `FLAG_SECURE`

Comment: That detects if my device is lockable--not if LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE is set.  At least that's what it looks like according to my testing.  Edit:  I could be wrong about this... looking into it further.

Comment: Just updated question with the code I used.  It's always returning true for me.